# Undo command Linux "rm"

Tags: shell, script

Please, I have used rm * in a script shell, it deleted all my files? (a typo)

Is there a solution to recover these files ?

Comment: Restore from backup

Comment: How can do that please ?

Comment: Definite duplicate ^